# How is the best way create a Task to collect massive data with Celery through RabbitMQ?

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, celery

I need to create a Worker that will stay running forever getting data from remote systems through `REST` calls. The response of those calls are a `JSON` Array with a lot of data.

When the task receives data from the remote system it splits and triggers  into a several small messages that is send over `RabbitMQ`.

As you can see, this behavior is like a traditional JOB.

I already created a `Celery Worker` with `Scheduler` (`celery.beat`) that calls some tasks every 10 minutes.

There are a few types of data in this sample structure:

```
{[
    "type1": {some structure},
    "type2": {another structure}, 
    ...
]}
```

**Is there a best way to get data from `REST API`, process, splits it and send through `RabbitMQ`?**

If you use Celery to get data from REST call, share with me how you did it.